# How to draw an arrow between two images in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, geometric-arc

I have to do this: to draw an arrow between two images from my canvas, so when I click the button with the arrow on it and I put click on one image to paste the arrow on it and then to draw the arrow as long as i need and to paste it to the second image.

Comment: Mmh, it's not so clear... could you give a small visual example of what you need ?

Comment: You need more than 2 points to draw an arc, how else are you going to determine size, start and sweep angle?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you clearly explain a) what you have (want) on the screen, in terms of boxes, buttons, arc, etc, and b) what you want to do (the user) in terms of mouse clicks and maybe click-n-drag operations. Thanks.

Comment: I am doing an editor ( BPMN Editor) and I have all kinds of things to represent like: events, activities, relations etc. So I have buttons for all this stuff, I mean when I press a button, on my canvas it is drawn an image wich represents the events or the activity. The button with the relation is the arrow button so I want to draw an arrow between two of my images, to put click on one image and to draw the arrow to the other image I click after.

Answer (score 1):

To draw an arc with two points, you'll need a predefined angle. I assume you have that part figured out.

To do this, you need to draw two arcs, one in each image. The arc will be bigger than each image, but in the first image you can just clip it where the arc exits the image going toward the second point.

In the second image, you need to offset the arc by the x and y distance between the origins of the two images. Then draw the arc in the second image from the first point to the second point and clip that part that is outside the image.

If you need a rubber band arc, you'll have to erase and redraw it whenever the mouse moves. If you want to draw on the space on the form between the images, you can do that using the proper offset.

Answer (score 1):

You have two point, so you can draw a line. Try this:

```
public class Shape
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public Shape A { get; set; }
    public Shape B { get; set; }
}
```

and the code:

```
private string _currentTool;
private readonly List<Shape> _shapes;
private readonly List<Line> _lines;
private Line _currentLine;

private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _currentTool = "img";
}

private void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _currentTool = "line";
}

private void PictureBox1MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch (_currentTool)
    {
        case "img":
            _shapes.Add(new Shape { Image = button1.Image, X = e.X, Y = e.Y });
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            break;
        case "line":
                var selectedShapes = _shapes.Where(shape => (shape.X - 10 < e.X) && (e.X < shape.X + 10) &&
                                                           (shape.Y - 10 < e.Y) && (e.Y < shape.Y + 10));
                if (selectedShapes.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var selectedShape = selectedShapes.First();
                    _currentLine = new Line {A = selectedShape};
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                }
            break;
    }
}

private void PictureBox1MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch (_currentTool)
    {
        case "line":
                var selectedShapes = _shapes.Where(shape => (shape.X - 10 < e.X) && (e.X < shape.X + 10) &&
                                                           (shape.Y - 10 < e.Y) && (e.Y < shape.Y + 10));
                if (selectedShapes.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var selectedShape = selectedShapes.First();
                    _currentLine.B = selectedShape;
                    _lines.Add(_currentTool);
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                }
            break;
    }
}

private void PictureBox1Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var shape in _shapes)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(shape.Image, shape.X, shape.Y);
    }
    foreach (var line in _lines)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), line.A.X, line.A.Y, line.B.X, line.B.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't draw anything :( . Maybe I did something wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Shape
{
public float X { get; set; }
public float Y { get; set; }
public Image Image { get; set; }

public bool Test_int(int x, int y)
    {
        if (((x <= this.x + (float)image.Width) && (x >= this.x)) && ((y <= this.y + (float)image.Height) && (y >= this.y)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}



public class Line
{
    public Shape A { get; set; }
    public Shape B { get; set; }
}
```

and the code

```
private string currentTool;
private readonly List<Shape> shapes;
private readonly List<Line> lines;
private Line currentLine;

private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentTool = "img";
}

private void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentTool = "line";
}


private void PictureBox1MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    switch (currentTool)
    {
        case "img":
            shapes.Add(new Shape { Image = button1.Image, X = e.X, Y = e.Y });
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            break;
        case "line":
            foreach (Shape shape1 in shapes)
                {

                    if (shape1.Test_int(e.X, e.Y))
                    {

                        currentLine = new Line { A = shape1 };

                    }

                }
                drawArea1.Invalidate();
        break;
    }
}

private void PictureBox1MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    switch (currentTool)
    {
        case "line":
            foreach (Shape shape1 in shapes)
            {

                if (shape1.Test_int(e.X, e.Y))
                {


                    currentLine.B = shape1;

                    }

                }
                lines.Add(currentLine);
                drawArea1.Invalidate();

            break;
    }
}

private void PictureBox1Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (var shape in shapes)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(shape.Image, shape.X, shape.Y);
    }
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1);
        Pen p2 = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        p2.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
        p2.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;

        float x1 = line.A.X+line.A.Image.Width ;
        float y1 = line.A.Y+line.A.Image.Height/2;
        float x2 = line.B.X;
        float y2 = line.B.Y+line.B.Image.Height/2;
        double angle = Math.Atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p2, x2, y2, x2 + (float)(Math.Cos(angle)), y2 + (float)(Math.Sin(angle)));

    }
}
```

Comment: This works and I draw the arrow a bit special, I mean I wanted the endCap with the ArrowArc to be bigger then c# draws it.

Comment: Try `e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(2, 2);` before drawing.